# Site.Master(1): Build (web): Could not load type 'xxx.SiteMaster'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make dynamic menus which will fetch Menus from the database rather than editing the front end of the software . The project was going fine till the time i clicked "Publish Website" button in MS visual Studio 2010 and am getting this error since

```
"\DynamicMenu\Site.Master(1): Build (web): Could not load type 'DynamicMenu.SiteMaster'"
```

Please Help

Thanks.

Comment: When the project is not build properly , you get this error.There is some error in the project.Build the project again and check the output window.

Comment: i did ..it's giving me the same error ...

Comment: Build the project and from the View menu in VS click Output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cause I can think of is that, you have marked your Site.Master.cs file as a content file.

It should have the build action as Compile.

Comment: I'm kind of new at Asp.net development ... can you please make it a bit more clearer ..! @nunespascal

Comment: Open your file Site.Master.cs, check if the namespace and class name are correct DynamicMenu.SiteMaster. Check that the `CodeFile` and `Inherits` attributes(First line of Site.Master) match the namespace and class. If those match then click on your cs file and look in the properties window. The cs file should have a build action of compile.